# Initial velocity and time of motion through water

Tags: classical-mechanics

What initial velocity has to have a ball at the height $h=1\ \text{m}$ in order to sink in the water to depth of $s=4\ \text{m}$? How long is the motion of a ball through water? A ball is made of material that has density $\rho=770\ \text{kg/m}^3$. Surface tension and friction are negligible.

**Question**: What is the relation between motion in vacuum and in water?

Is it necessary to know the density of a ball to find the time of motion through water and initial velocity?

Comment: If the ball has negligible mass but finite density, it must be very small. Its density is less than that of water, so it would normally be buoyant - but clearly if it is penetrating 4 m into the water, it must be going very fast. There is a retarding force due to the water being displaced - we normally consider that "friction". I'm afraid you are overconstraining the problem... please tell us the context in which you are trying to solve this, because the "real" solution is probably not the one you are asking for.

Comment: @Floris Are you saying that the mass should not be negligible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, one would solve a problem like this by assuming a certain model for the drag - for a sphere, we often use

$$F = \frac12 \rho v^2 A C_D$$

With $\rho$ = density of liquid (1000 kg/m$^3$), $v$ the velocity, $A$ the projected area $\pi r^2$ and $C_D$ the drag coefficient (which is a function of Reynolds number but usually approximated as 0.5 for a sphere).

If the object has a mass $m$, then the rate of change of momentum is

$$\dot p = m \dot v = F$$

With $m=\frac43 \pi r^3 \rho_s$, we rewrite as

$$\frac43 \pi r^3 \rho_s \dot v =\frac12\rho v^2 \pi r^2 C_D$$

Rearranging, we get a differential equation for velocity:

$$\frac{dv}{v^2} = \frac{3}{16}\frac{1}{r} \frac{\rho}{\rho_s} dt$$

This gives the velocity as a function of time:

$$\frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{v_0} - \frac{3}{16}\frac{1}{r} \frac{\rho}{\rho_s}t$$

As you can see, the mass comes into the calculation... or alternatively, the radius. Unless you are expected to make some assumptions - that is something I cannot deduce from your question.

You may be interested in Newton's analysis of [impact depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth) which is a simplified model that tells us that the depth of penetration is a function of the ratio of densities and the length of the projectile:

$$D = L\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2}$$

Telling you that a longer projectile, or one of greater density, will penetrate deeper. But that is presumably not the analysis you are looking for, as you are giving the wrong parameters (no dimension of the object is given).